# removing the shadow or blank space form AppBarLayout +Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, space, android-appbarlayout

**Updated :Its not duplicate question**

I tried many solution for remove blank ,margin or space or shadow from *left and right* side but its not work for me.

[image: Here is my screen]

**Here is my `xml` code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:supportsRtl="false"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <include layout="@layout/header_one_layout" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**and i also tried below solution**

```
Toolbar toolbar;
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);


    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0); //padding programmatically
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

> I want to put shadow or elevation in bottom so i'm not use `app:elevation="0dp"`

any help will appreciate , thank you in advance.

Comment: **`app:elevation="0dp"`**

Comment: @Nilesh - but i want to put shadow or elevation in bottom , because app:elevation="0dp" is remove shadow from all side, pls help

Comment: did you try **`app:elevation="5dp"`**

Comment: it means it will take shadow just reduce its default dp

Comment: do you want to add shodow or want to remove it?

Comment: Please add   android:background="@null" line in AppBarLayout like <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

Comment: @shruti - no any effect using android:background="@null"

Comment: i want to put shadow in bottom only so i cant use app:elevation="0dp"

Comment: This code is working perfect <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

Comment: plz try above code , its working perfect on my device with bottom shadow

Comment: Try with this theme
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="23">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: @**Mohit Kanada** - yes this solution is perfect, when i change my theme you given it works as i want , thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Nilesh- it'snot a duplicate brother, please be careful before  next-time someone's question marked as duplicate, thanks